# nuxt js useFetch() not showing data in my browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3, usefetch

its not showing data in my site. what is the problem i cant find it. please help im noob sorry. the url has json data and has key "featured". here is my code below.

```
<template>
   <q-card v-for="article in formattedJSON.featured" :key="article.id">
    <q-img :src="article.image" @load="imageLoaded" />
     <q-card-section>
      <NuxtLink
       :to="article.channel.url"
        class="text-channel text-caption q-mb-sm text-uppercase text-weight-bold"
        style="text-decoration: none"
        >{{ article.channel.name }}
     </NuxtLink>
      <p class="q-mb-sm text-header4">{{ article.title }}</p>
     <p class="q-mb-xl text-data">{{ article.blurb }}</p>
   </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</template>

<script setup>
 const { data: formattedJSON } = await useFetch(
 "https://featured/get/");
</script>`
```

show the data in the page like the img, channel name, title and blurb.

Comment: try  useAsyncData

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Did you try to debug formattedJSON? Did you try to add something besides q-card to make sure it's rendered at all? That you use await in setup means that Suspense needs to be used in order to render the comp. If the comp is not route page, you need to care of this yourself

Comment: `https://featured/get/` would try to GET date from a domain `featured` using `https` - but `featured` is not a valid domain

Comment: Check your console or network tab, should definitely have some tips there.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using JSON.parse(formattedJSON.featured), as it's possible that the featured data isn't in the expected object format.